# Angular go to outside page using link

Tags: html, angular, hyperlink, href

Using link for open another page outside of project

```
<div class="info-line">
   <mat-icon class="s-20 ml-2">
    language
   </mat-icon>
   <a class="h3" href="https://www.google.kz/">
     Web Page
   </a>
</div>
```

but when click to link, opened this page: http://localhost:4200/google.kz - local page, not "google.kz"

How to make, open google.kz outsite link, not trying to find in local page?

Comment: The markup you have should work fine. What you are describing is what typically happens if you have instead `<a class="h3" href="google.kz">` or `<a class="h3" href="/google.kz">`

Comment: Are you sure you put the `https` perfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `target="blank"` as follows.

```
<a class="h3" href="https://www.google.kz/" target="_blank">
```

> [**target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)
>
> Where to display the linked URL, as the name for a browsing context (a tab, window, or `iframe`).
>
> `_blank`: usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new window instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you've described it, but another way of doing it is using the document.location api.

Example:

```
<div class="info-line">
   <mat-icon class="s-20 ml-2">
    language
   </mat-icon>
   <a class="h3" (click)="navigate()">
     Web Page
   </a>
</div>
```

inside your component:

```
navigate(){
     document.location = "https://www.google.kz/"
}
```

Comment: document.location gives exception - Type "https://www.google.kz/" is not assignable to type 'Location'.